# How to force a filter to apply to a certain column?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

The data source table

```
state   company   income   incomeGenDate    taxPay   taxPayGenDate
AL      xxx       100      2013             50       2013
IL      mmm       100      2013             30       2013
AL      yyy       200      2012             60       2013
IL      zzz       300      2012             30       2012
IL      mmm       200      2013             50       2014
```

I want to include `incomeGenDate` as a filter that would apply to ONLY `income` column. And `taxPayGenDate` must filter  ONLY `taxPay` column.

---

Here is the desired outcome if I apply two filters : `incomeGenDate = 2013` and let's say `state = IL`

```
state   company   sum_income       sum_taxPay   
    IL      zzz        0               30     
    IL      mmm       300              80
```

In the above pivot, `state = IL` is a global filter therefore it applied to all rows. So only IL state companies are left (`mmm , zzz` )

1) `incomeGenDate = 2013` filter applied ONLY to `income` column  so that `zzz` company's sum_income in 2013 is 0 and `mmm` sum_income =  300 .

2) However, even though `zzz` company paid tax of 30 in 2012, the `incomeGenDate = 2013` filter did not apply for the `tax` because it applies only to  `income` column

---

I tried to inlude the two column in the filter area, however, they worked as filters for all values, so that `incomeGenDate` was filtering `income` as well as `taxPay`.

How can I force a filter to be applied to a particular column?

Thank You!

Comment: @pnuts Thank you for reply I have edited my question with a real descriptive example

Comment: in 2013 zzz company had no income therefore it is 0

Comment: zzz had a positive income of 300, but that was back in 2012. Since we applied filter `incomeGenDate = 2013` all 2012 `income` values go away.

Comment: Yes. sum_income and sum_taxPay are calculated. But `incomeGenDate` should apply to ONLY `income` column. And `taxPayGenDate` should filter ONLY taxPay column

Comment: I know one way how to do this. I could create multiple `subpivot` tables on separate sheets.  But that would be awkward and not neat. I was hoping that there was a way to do this in one pivot table. If there is some VBA script that would facilitate this, I will be very thankful too.